# Strongloop AngularJS reflection services

Tags: angularjs, rest, reflection, strongloop

I've a Java developer who's begun working in the Javascript enterprise domain. Specifically I've begun working with Strongloop/Loopback API and AngularJS in the client.

I'm creating entities with ease with Strongloop and am very impressed with how quickly I can generate an expanded model. When it comes to the client  however things appear to slow down as I have to manually create the Angular Controllers, Services and the crud template views.

I've used reflection in Java considerably in the past and I found it to be very effective. I was hoping someone might be able to let me know if there's either a reflective way to initialise Controllers so that I could have one EntityController if you like that would export the CRUD methods. Alternatively if there's a tool that might be able to access the restful api and generate generic templates, controllers and services for the restful API?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Mark.

Comment: Check out ngResource https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource and RestAngular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

Comment: Thanks Shaun I'll take a look at restangular once I've gone through the $resource stuff so that I can gauge the difference. Just getting started with Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for [loopback angularjs SDK](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK). 
It will not generate views and controllers but you will have angularJS services generated that contains all the LoopBack models and methods you have defined. You have to register the AngularJS module  lbServices  as a dependency of your app.

Documentation covers this very well with step-by-step instructions how to setup client application.

After you setup loopback angular client, then it is easy to use models in your controllers. All you have to do is to add your model as a dependency in your controller.

If you want to avoid manual work of generating angular controllers, routes, views etc then you should consider using one of the angular application generators ( i.e. [yeoman generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)  ).

To make long story short:

1. use angular generator to generate angular application.
2. generate angular services using [loopback angularjs SDK](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/AngularJS+JavaScript+SDK).
3. add loopback model as dependency to your controller or service

See also  [Angular SDK built-in models API](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-sdk-angular/)

Comment: Thanks very much A.Z. I believe yeoman may be exactly what I'm looking for! I went through the LoopBack AngularJS SDK tutorial and am using the lb-services. js as a dependency in my controller. But I was hoping to avoid the boilerplate coding associated with the views and controllers for the front end. I'll give that a shot right now!